# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak

Tags: android

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'//error: mixing versions
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

This is my dependency in my android app.
I'm using google maps and I suddenly can't compile and this error comes up.

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak, sources=[Unknown source file], tool     name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I think this has something to do with my gradle.build 
I really don't understand what 'don't mix versions mean'. How am I suppose to know which versions I should use?

Comment: Try [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) . Add only the module which you need . Do not add `com.google.android.gms:play-services:` completely .

Answer (score 2):

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'` is part of `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` library which in the build.gradle file you should use the same version for both of them

Answer (score 1):

- Add Google play services `classpath` in **Parent Project**

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // Add Google repo 
    }
}
```

- Apply `Google play services` plugin at the bottom of **App module** dependencies.

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'//error: mixing versions Because it's already included on last dependency Please ready this below comments.

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // You may not need this line after using ONLY what you need from Google play services.

//    Avoid using bundled version of Google Play services SDK. less... (⌘F1)
//    Google Play services SDK's can be selectively included, which enables a smaller APK size. Consider declaring dependencies on individual Google Play services SDK's. If you are using Firebase API's (http://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), Android Studio's Tools → Firebase assistant window can automatically add just the dependencies needed for each feature.  More info: http://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```